# Laravel Eloquent how to make one-to-any relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have model 'Transaction' which represent a message to be send, and the transaction shall have a relationship called 'recipients', each recipient might be a 'Group' Or a 'Person'.

***The relationship is (One transaction has many recipients)***

- What type of eloquent relationship should I used?
- How to implement that?

Transaction:

```php
        Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->enum('destination_type', DestinationType::getValues());
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Recipient:

```php
        Schema::create('recipients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('recipient_id');
            $table->string('recipient_type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Profile:

```php
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->enum('type', ProfileType::getValues());
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('arabic_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('english_name');
            $table->string('email')->nullable()->unique();
            $table->string('mobile')->nullable();
            $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Group:

```php
        Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: you should make the one to one relationship in your `Model` and relationships in the database is an optional option and it's just for more speed and errors of database

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one can help, it's always good before asking a question, read the documentation

Comment: Hello, @SamRaskul I already have read the documentation and  I found 'Polymorphic one-to-many' and I feel it is what I need but I didn't understand how to implement it. The relationship between transaction and recipient is one transaction to many recipients which could be many groups or many profiles.

Also my English is weak but I hope you get my point.

Comment: you can write your application without the Polymorphic relationship. Polymorphic is an option to design the database more efficiently. anyway, the first priority for you is learning normal relationships. have a nice day